# casting and integer conversion confusion

Tags: c

I feel like **6.3.1.3**  of standard is already included in **6.3.1.8**

but reading:

> Otherwise, the new type is signed and the value cannot be represented
>   in it; either the result is implementation-defined or an
>   implementation-defined signal is raised.

It is not mentioned this case there. So is 6.3.1.3 for *integer promotions* only and when there is casting what is the order of conversion. Is it promotion and then casting or casting then promotions or only casting .

Comment: What standard? C or C++ and which version of either?

Comment: It is C but same rules or ?

Comment: If you are asking about specific sections and paragraphs of some document, you better specify what document you are talking about.

Comment: it is from C99 standard.

Comment: The C99 standard is old; it has been superseded by the C11 standard for 5 years now.

Comment: Maybe but I need to know the previous standards and then it will be easy to know the new rules or features in C11

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of circumstances under which a C compiler will insert code to convert one datatype to another. These include *explicit conversions* performed by the cast operator, and a variety of implicit conversions. Both of these conversion contexts are covered by §6.3.1:

> 1. Several operators convert operand values from one type to another automatically. This subclause specifies the result required from such an *implicit conversion*, as well as those that result from a cast operation (an *explicit conversion*).

§6.3.1.3 explains how the conversions are performed, without specifying *when* the conversions are performed. The same procedure is used both for explicit and implicit conversions; to perform a conversion, it is only needed to know the original type and the desired type.

§6.3.1.8 explains how the destination type is selected in some common contexts, without specifying the algorithm for the conversion. So the two clauses are entirely complementary. One describes how a conversion is done, and the other describes which conversion is done.

§6.3.1.8 applies to certain arithmetic operators whose operands must be of the same type. (As noted, this clause doesn't apply to *all* arithmetic operators and you have to read the description of each individual operator to see the exceptions.) It should be noted that the algorithm to select the target types for both operands only results in "widening" conversions. The target type is always as wide as or wider than the original type. It is possible that a signed integer will be converted to an unsigned integer of the same width, but an unsigned type is only converted to a signed type when the signed type is wide enough to represent all values of the unsigned type.

The implementation of signed to unsigned conversions is precisely defined without implementation-defined behaviour in §6.3.1.3p2;. Thus, paragraph §6.3.1.3p3 will never apply to the conversions required by §6.3.1.8. This is also true of the *integer promotions* defined in §6.3.1.1p2, which can be triggered by the algorithm described in §6.3.1.8.

In other contexts in which automatic or explicit conversion takes place, narrowing conversions may be requested; if the target of a narrowing conversion is signed, §6.3.1.3p3 may apply.

Comment: For `double i; char s; i=i+s;` there is no integer promotion for `s` right ?

Comment: @Sabrina: The second case in 6.3.1.8p1 is "Otherwise, if the corresponding real type of either operand is double, the other
operand is converted, without change of type domain, to a type whose
corresponding real type is double." That applies, so `s` is converted to a `double`. To do the conversion, we need to use 6.3.1.4p2, "When a value of integer type is converted to a real floating type, if the value being converted can be represented exactly in the new type, it is unchanged." That applies in this case. No integer promotion anywhere in that procedure.

Comment: Technically, I suppose, it is possible that a `char` would not fit into a `double` without losing accuracy, but that would require very wide `char`s and very narrow `double`s. I doubt whether such an architecture exists, but you never know.

Comment: Also, I think my comment above illustrates the difference between the "what conversion" and "how to convert" questions, which was the original point of the answer.

Comment: Last question please: for conversion from unsigned integer to signed integer with greater rank is it sign extended ?

Comment: and if there is no `char a,c,b; c=a+b;` here also there is no integer promotion as there is no int or unsigned int.

Comment: When an unsigned value is converted to a signed type of greater rank, the value is the unchanged, the same as the conversion from char to double noted above. How that is implemented at the hardware level is not specified by 6.3.1; in the case of integers we can deduce that any extra bits are set to 0, but that's an implementation detail. If `a` and `b` are `char` then `a+b` causes integer promotion of both arguments; the result of the addition will be `int`, and converting the result back to a `char` could overflow unless `char` is an unsigned type. So `char c = a + b;` is not advised.

Comment: @sabrina, as before the precise details may vary with unorthodox architectures. In particular, if `char` is an unsigned type which is as wide as an `int` then the integer promotion in `a+b` will convert both operands to `unsigned int` (which presumably does not change the underlying representation) and the type of the addition will be therefore also be `unsigned int`, thus avoiding the risk of overflow. But that architecture is uncommon.

Comment: but there is no presence for int or unsigned int in the expression why there is integer promotion for result.

Comment: @sabrina, because the standard says so, in 6.3.1.8. First it checks if an operand is a floating point type. If not, it applies the integer promotions to both operands, and then proceeds with the rest of the algorithm.

Comment: @sabrina, it's the third "otherwise" in that clause, if you haven't found it yet.

Comment: `The following` **`may be used in an expression`** `wherever an` **`int or unsigned int may be used:`** feel like there is ambiguity here.

Comment: @sabrina: perhaps it would help if you explain a specific example where the standatd, *read as a whole* appears to describe two different behaviours. Because I think that the prescribed behaviour is clear in every case. The clause you are quoting is not sufficient *by itself* but it is accompanied by the rest of the standard.

Comment: Thank you for your time @rici !